# Only one line in logstash-plain.log

Tags: logstash

On CentOS, when I start Logstash with this command:

`sudo systemctl start logstash`

It produces this line in /var/log/logstash/logstash-plain.log:

`[2017-08-15T13:52:14,119][INFO ][logstash.agent ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}`

I can’t figure out what is wrong (why it is not sending data to ElasticSearch) based on this single line in log.

When I was using Logstash on Windows, during start it produces ten to fifteen lines (warn and info) in command prompt. What can I do to get more lines in logstash log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using input jdbc to access postgres database. I needed to install jdbc driver for Logstash. On CentOS command is:

`bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-input-jdbc`

After installation, log file had more than 10 lines.

It would be much better if Logstash logged error that driver is missing for input that is used in config.